# Validating form inputs of a perticular form

Tags: javascript, prototype, validation

I have the following code that makes sure inputs on forms aren't blank, however I have 2 forms on a page and only want this to check the inputs on the form called `<form id="my_form"`...

```
var valid_form = true;
$$('input').each(function(item){
    if( item.value == '' ) valid_form = false;
});
```

Please can somebody tell me how to do this?

Comment: is the double $$ above a typo? IIRC that looks like prototype syntax.

Comment: It's jQuery, he mentioned it in the tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var valid_form = true;
$$('#my_form input').each(function(item){
    if( item.value == '' ) valid_form = false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can give a different ID for each of you forms like frmLogin and frmSearch and then when one of your forms is submitted you check only the inputs in it.

```
var valid_form = true;
$('form').submit(function () { 
 $(this).find('input').each(function(item){ 
   if( item.value == '' ) valid_form = false;  
 }) 
});
```

Or if you check your forms after a button has been clicked you can do it like this.

```
$('#yourButton').click(function () {
 $('#my_form input').each(function(item){ 
   if( item.value == '' ) valid_form = false;  
 }) 
});
```